# PHP: How to get all regular expression matches?

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to get all regular expression matches in PHP? I need a script that will, for example, match `.+` in `abc` and give the result:

Array(`a`, `b`, `c`, `ab`, `bc`, `abc`)

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617055/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: This is not what regular expressions are meant to do, and there is no reliable way to do this, besides writing your own (subset of) regex parser and doing something different then all other regex implementations.

Comment: @shamittomar No, I thought it was clear enough that `.+` was only an example.

Comment: @Wrikken Maybe you should post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a defined set of "all matches" in a regular expression.

For example, what if your pattern were `.+.+`?  What is matched by the first `.+`?  What is matched by the second?

A string may match a particular RE binding in multiple different ways, and which substring is captured by different parts of the RE may depend on things like greedy vs. non-greedy matching.  But there is no defined way to iterate over all the different possible captures.  You'd have to dramatically change the way that REs are processed to do this.

Comment: `.+.+` on `abc` would give Array(`ab`, `bc`, `abc`)

Comment: I understand your answer, but I am still hoping for a solution, like a custom library that can answer my prayer :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is at the overlap, you want to match 'ab' and also 'bc' which you won't be able to do with a simple regex.  However consider the following.

You can split out every character with either of these lines:

```
preg_match_all('/./', 'abc', $matches);
str_split('abc');
```

Giving you: array('a', 'b', 'c').

And the following will split pairs of characters with the remaining single character:

```
preg_match_all('/.{2}|./', 'abc', $matches);
```

Giving you: array('ab', 'c');

So you could play around with combinations/variations of these to achieve your outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a bit old, but there still might be someone who needs the answer.

Look at the `flags` parameter for [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function