# Every possible combination of a string in php

Tags: php, string

I need to build strings in PHP with every possible combination like

> s5z-s4z-s3z-s2z-s1z

where the 's' then the number are always in the same position.
the only difference is whether there is a z on the end or not.

So for example I would have

- s5z-s4z-s3z-s2z-s1
- s5z-s4z-s3z-s2z-s1z
- s5z-s4z-s3z-s2-s1
- s5z-s4z-s3z-s2z-s1
- s5z-s4z-s3z-s2-s1z
- s5z-s4z-s3-s2-s1z
- etc.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please re-tag your question as "homework". Also, it's a dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617055/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: duplicate of homework? that's... lame(lame())..

Comment: @MoeTsao I guess the OP doesn't understand that he won't have access to SO during the final exam... :)

Comment: @alfasin What if he does? Should we setup a "test_question" tag? Advise all school teachers to monitor this during programming language test? We can then tag it with the community's force

Answer (score 3):

So basically it all relies on "is the z there or not". This can easily be translated to a binary number, where each `0` represents the `z` not being there, and each `1` indicated the presence of the `z`.

As a result, you need only loop through all the numbers.

```
$length = 5;
$max = bindec(str_repeat("1",$length));
$out = Array();
for( $i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
  $entry = Array();
  for( $x=0; $x<$length; $x++) $entry[] = "s".($length-$x).($i & (1<<$x) ? "z" : "");
  $out[] = implode("-",$entry);
}
echo implode(" ",$out);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried all sorts of things and could not get it. thank you very much for this.