# No Repeat, Exact Length, All Possible combinations of a string in php

Tags: php

I am looking for an algorithm that will provide me with all possible outcomes of same length and no repeat.

```
INPUT
---------------
abc


OUTPUT
---------------
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Comment: ya i have tried.. but its not of exact length.. got help from some prevous post.. but was not apporpriate..

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here man: [How to generate all permutations of a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617055/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-php)

```
// function to generate and print all N! permutations of $str. (N = strlen($str)).
function permute($str,$i,$n) {
   if ($i == $n)
       print "$str\n";
   else {
        for ($j = $i; $j < $n; $j++) {
          swap($str,$i,$j);
          permute($str, $i+1, $n);
          swap($str,$i,$j); // backtrack.
       }
   }
}

// function to swap the char at pos $i and $j of $str.
function swap(&$str,$i,$j) {
    $temp = $str[$i];
    $str[$i] = $str[$j];
    $str[$j] = $temp;
}   

$str = "hey";
permute($str,0,strlen($str)); // call the function.
```