# PHP regular expression permutations

Tags: php, regex

I have a string e.g. `HRJSHR` and search for a way to find all possible permutations of `A-Z` with the length of 2 or more letters. For example

- HR, RJ, JS, SH, HR
- HRJ, RJS, JSH, SHR
- HRJS, RJSH, JSHR
- HRJSH, RJSHR
- HRJSHR

`|[A-Z]{2,}|` just returns the whole string "HRJSHR" and `|[A-Z]{2}|` just that ones whith a length of 2 letters. `|[A-Z]{2+}|` doesn't works.

Which regular expression will find all permutations of A-Z with a length of 2 ore more letters in the string?

Comment: IMHO it isn't possible with a single regex. You have to loop from 2 to the length of the string.

Comment: You can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617055/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: Are you using preg_match_all? or just preg_match?

Comment: Vote for reopen because from `ABC` OP wants to match `AB`,`BC`,`ABC` and not `AB`,`BC`,`AC`,`CB`,`CA`,`BA` as I understrand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could capture inside a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?=([A-Z]{2}))` would match all substrings composed of two `[A-Z]` such as `HR`,`RJ`,`JS`,`SH`,`HR`. See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rO9cL2/1).

[image]

Combine it with a loop to get the desired result:

```
$str =  "HRJSHR"; $res = array();

for($i=2; preg_match_all('/(?=([A-Z]{'.$i.'}))/', $str, $out); $i++)
  $res[$i] = $out[1];

print_r($res);
```

See [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/285701), *outputs to*:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => HR
            [1] => RJ
            [2] => JS
            [3] => SH
            [4] => HR
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => HRJ
            [1] => RJS
            [2] => JSH
            [3] => SHR
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => HRJS
            [1] => RJSH
            [2] => JSHR
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => HRJSH
            [1] => RJSHR
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => HRJSHR
        )

)
```

For a result without grouping by length, use:
`$res = array_merge($res, $out[1]);` instead of `$res[$i] = $out[1];`