# Number permutations in PHP with repeated characters

Tags: php

I store a number in a string. My code shuffles the digits into different permutations.

Example if the input is:

```
'123'
```

then the output permutations will be:

```
123,132,213,231,321,312
```

If the input string has repeated digits, my code does not work, and goes into an infinite loop.

Example inputs that don't work:

```
11,22,33,44,55,455,998,855,111,555,888,222 etc.
```

My code:

```
<?php
function factorial($n){
    if($n==1) return $n;

    return $n*factorial($n-1);
}

$a   = '1234';
$_a  = str_split($a);
$num = count($_a);
$ele_amnt = factorial($num);
$output = array();
while(count($output) < $ele_amnt){
    shuffle($_a);
    $justnumber = implode('', $_a);
    if(!in_array($justnumber , $output))
        $output[] = $justnumber;

}
sort($output);
print_r($output);
```

Can anyone explain why and how to fix it?

Comment: What does this have to do with the programming language C?

Comment: Please don't tag questions with [tag:c] when they have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry sir.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617055/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: @mitkosoft thank you

Answer (score 2):

Short version: Your terminating condition for the while loop "is" [permutational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) while your `if(!in_array...)` test "is" [combinational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

---

Let's assume `$a=11;`: then `$ele_amnt` is `2` and your while loop will stop when the array $output contains more than one element.
Your shuffle/implode code can produce either the string `<firstelement><seconelement>` or `<secondelement><firstelement>`, both being `11`.
And `if(!in_array( $justnumber , $output))` allows only one of them to be appended to $output. So count($output) will be 1 after the first iteration and will stay 1 in perpetuity. Same for every $a with duplicate digits.

---

[shuffle()](http://docs.php.net/shuffle) changes the position of elements in an array *at random*. SO, the performance of the algorithm depends on ....luck ;-)
You might be interested in something like https://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics instead.

Comment: The OP's code works for permutations (even though it does brute force, and will get less efficient for longer strings).  The problem lies in the repeated characters.  You have linked to a package that has this as a description: "A package that returns all the combinations and permutations, without repitition"

Comment: "The OP's code works for permutations" - no, it mixes permutation and combination and therefore doesn't work (i.e. there are cases where it doesn't work). If the part about " You have linked to a package" has a point, I've missed it.

Comment: I originally misread the question as the OP wanting to have repeated output characters.  I.e.  Given an input of ab, output: aa,ab,ba,bb,a,b.

Answer (score 0):

Your output array will contain less permutations if you have repeated characters in your input.  So your loop never completes.

You could map your inputs, then later map back from your output, and then filter to do as you desire:

```
// For a string '122' we get the permutations of '123' first and then process.

$output = op_code_no_repeats('123');

$filtered = array();
foreach($output as $permutation) {
    $filtered[] = str_replace('3', '2', $permutation);
}
$filtered = array_unique($filtered);

var_dump($filtered);
```

Outputs:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '122' (length=3)
  2 => string '212' (length=3)
  3 => string '221' (length=3)
```

Your code with guards on the factorial and permutation functions:

```
function factorial($n)
{
    if(! is_int($n) || $n < 1)
        throw new Exception('Input must be a positive integer.');
    if($n==1)
        return $n;

    return $n * factorial($n-1);
};

function op_code_no_repeats($a) {

    $_a  = str_split($a);

    if(array_unique($_a) !== $_a)
        throw new Exception('Does not work for strings with repeated characters.');

    $num = count($_a);
    $perms_count = factorial($num);

    $output = array();
    while(count($output) < $perms_count){
        shuffle($_a);
        $justnumber = implode('', $_a);
        if(!in_array($justnumber , $output))
            $output[] = $justnumber;
    }
    sort($output);

    return $output;
}
```