# Maximum executiontime exceeded when printing array

Tags: php, arrays, fatal-error

I have the following code, which prints all combinations of the given numbers. It returns a fatal error when `$numbers` contains two equal numbers.

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
C:/Apache24/htdocs/index.php on line 18
```

**My Code:**

```
<?php
$numbers = array("2","1","4");
$numberofelements = count($numbers);
$factorial = 1;
for ($i=1; $i<=$numberofelements; $i++)
{
         $factorial *= $i;
}
$quantitycombinations = $factorial;
$numbersdrawn = array();
while(true)
{
    $exists = false;
    $numberdrawn1 = "";
    shuffle($numbers);
    $numberdrawn1 = implode("", $numbers);
    strval($numberdrawn1);
    foreach ($numbersdrawn as $value) {
            if(strval($value)==$numberdrawn1)
            {
                $exists = true;
            }
        }
    if(!$exists){
        array_push($numbersdrawn, $numberdrawn1);
        if(count($numbersdrawn)==$quantitycombinations)
        {
            foreach($numbersdrawn as $item)
            {
                echo $item."<br>";          
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your basic algorithm for this is: generate a random attempt until you find a new one, then once you've created all of them, show them in a list. The problem is that with any repeating digits, you're never going to hit the number of combinations, because they aren't unique. This isn't a problem you can solve with brute force, unless you're smarter about calculating the number of total combinations.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617055/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-php) for some alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop doesn't stop until the number of combinations in `$numbersdrawn` is equal to `$factorial`. But when there are duplicates, there aren't that many different combinations, because some of the combinations are identical to each other.

E.g. if the numbers are 1, 2, 3, the combinations are  123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321.

But if the numbers are 1, 2, 2, the combinations are only 122, 212, 221.

You need to divide `$factorial` by the number of repeated elements to get `$quantitycombinations`.