# How to shuffle n digits number to arrays with PHP?

Tags: php

(I don't think my question is clear enough to explain my needs. Apologize for my English for that.)

I want to shuffle the number to the last possibility. I can only think of this. It seems working but it's not give me all the number as a loop runs.

```
$num="123";//given number
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $num2[$i]=str_shuffle($num);            
}//for
print_r($num2);
print_r(array_unique($num2));
```

As a result.

```
print_r($tod);//Array ( [0] => 132 [1] => 123 [2] => 321 [3] => 231 [4] => 312 [5] => 231 
[6] => 231 [7] => 231 [8] => 312 [9] => 312 )
```

And I want only the unique array. So I put `array_unique()`. Then I got...

```
print_r(array_unique($tod));//Array ( [0] => 132 [1] => 123 [2] => 321 [3] => 231 [4] => 312 )
```

I want the loop (or not) to give me all possible number from the `$num` everytime. Or is there any function/method to get me this result more accurate?

As you see $num="123". I expect the result are 123, 132, 213, 231, 321 and 312.

Comment: So you need all permutations of a number?

Comment: I don't know what to call but as you see `$num="123"`. I expect the result are `123`,`132`,`213`,`231`,`321` and `312`.

Comment: Not sure about any inbuilt function but you can create your own. str_shuffle will just shuffle the string. It may or may not generate all the unique permutations all the time, hence it isn't correct.

Comment: The problem is the loop. Sometimes it gives me complete shuffle. But mostly not.

Comment: Because you are running 10 times and randomly shuffling and hoping to get the 6 numbers in 10 tries.

Comment: Got answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853960/1620626 It's about permutations of a string in PHP. Thanks for every suggestions!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

Comment: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb8bf4c5ca7b2a1f4e7da53754531e99b149ce8c